# Can I play SimCity on two computers at the same time?

Tags: origin, drm, simcity-2013

I'm not familiar with Origin's DRM (or the one that will be used on the next SimCity), but if I got the game, would I and my girlfriend be able to play it at the same time, each on their own computer at home, or would we need two separate Origin accounts and buy the game twice?

Comment: Since some people where able to get a hands on and play it, isn't it safe to ask this? I'd like to comparise this question with an other, frequently patched game. It may not be possible at this time but the developer might add it later. Nevertheless, the question is asked now and the answer is now No. If it changes, the answer can be updated or an other can be accepted. If this isn't the way to go, then I stand corrected.

Comment: @kalina - That's over-stretching it. The answer has been given already in the information about the game, even before release. The fact it's always online and relying on an Origin account to actually play answers the question. This might change in the future, but the time for it to change won't have anything to do with the release. So answers can be edited accordingly.

Comment: The game will required you to log into an account.  Because of this access to the same account multiple times at once is very unlikely.  You will require multiple copies and seperate accounts since EA does not allow multiple copies of the same game on the same Origin account.

Comment: This question could have been answered without experimentation.  Write down all the ways this scenario could be handled, then figure out the most unpleasant one.  That is the one that EA will choose.

Comment: Unlike current popular belief, I was able to do this with my wife. granted I wasnted able to play on the same region but we were able create our own seperate region and play at the same time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With Origin, you can install as many copies as you like. But when you start the game, you need to log in Origin. You cannot login at two different computers at the same time.

If you are playing and your girlfriend logs in, you will be put in offline mode. It seems like you have to be online to play the game. See [this link](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2012/03/28/simcity-to-be-crippled-by-always-on-lets-change-this/).

Answer (score 2):

**No** - it will not be possible for you to play SimCity twice with a single account. In order for you to both be able to play at the same time you will each need your own *Origin* account and your own copy of *SimCity*. This was confirmed [during a Reddit AMA with a Maxis employee](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/14umm1/we_are_the_simcity_dev_team_from_maxis_amaa/c7gmhqu) where it was stated that if you lose your internet connection during gameplay, you will not immediately be disconnected but if you don't re-establish a connection you will be kicked out of your current game:

> We will allow you to play for as long as we can preserve your game state. This will most likely be minutes.

In addition, it is highly likely that features such as the Global Market and trading within multi-city regions will require a persistent internet connection to function properly.

Comment: This behavior is actually expected.  In the past the physical disk would be required and provide the same limits.

Comment: http://uk.pc.gamespy.com/pc/sim-city-5/1221798p1.html "Yes, you will have to register an Origin account in order to play, and yes, you must be online in order to start playing. EA has confirmed that you will not be kicked out if your connection is interrupted."

Comment: @DavidB I've updated my answer - I did experience various instances during the beta where I was kicked back out to the main menu, since EA has confirmed this isn't how retail is going to play then this must have been something specific to the beta.

Comment: Isn't the conclusion wrong given the information?  Couldn't I connect to Origin.  Start the game.  Unplug my network.  Then connect and start on a different machine with the same account?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot be logged to the same Origin account twice, nor playing the same game (bought only once) together.

Otherwise we could build up a legit sharing community where we buy a copy and share account infos to play together with a minimal expense! :)

So, answering your question, if you want 2 people to play a game you need 2 Origin accounts and therefore 2 bought copies of the game itself.